# List and Strings issues in C

Tags: c, string, list, project

I made a list to do some data treatment and I'm having an issue that I don't find the cause, for me my code seems right but there are issues.

What I'm trying to do is the following :
I have a list that contains x elements. I want to add an element p in the list then take every x element, add p to the string they represent, and add them to the list. (the list by itself works great it's just that operation that causes troubles).

The problem is that when I do that and when I try to display the list the first x+p elements are displayed well, but after I see some strange characters that have nothing to do with the inputs.

Here are the functions I use :

```
void addFirst(struct list *l, char *key)
{
  struct node *x = createNode(key) ;
  if (l->size == 0)
  {
    l->first = x;
  }
  else
  {
    x->next = l->first;
    l->first = x;
  }
  l->size++;
  return;
}

void showList(struct list* l)
{
    struct node *p=l->first;
    while (p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \n",p->key);
        p=p->next;
    }
    return;
}

void copyPlus(struct list* l,char *ch)
{
    struct node *p=l->first;
    addFirst(l,ch);
    while (p!=NULL)
    {
        int len1=strlen(p->key);
        char cat[len1+2];
        strcpy(cat,p->key);
        strcat(cat,ch);
        cat[len1+1] = '\0';
        printf("[%s] \n",cat);
        addFirst(l,cat);
        printf("{%s} \n",l->first->key);
        p=p->next;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    struct list *A=createList();
    addFirst(A,"1");
    addFirst(A,"2");
    addFirst(A,"4");
    copyPlus(A,"3");
    printf("=%s= \n",A->first->key); //this one works!
    printf("=%s= \n",A->first->next->key);
    printf("=%s= \n",A->first->next->next->key);
    showList(A);
    deleteList(A);
}
```

I skipped the irrelevant stuffs, it's a classic list.

Node is defined that way :

```
struct node
{
  struct node *next;
  char *key;
};
```

After further ivestigation it appears that the process is working correctly (the two //printf in copyPlus work the way they should). And the last //printf doesn't display anything, even if I do A->first->next->next->next. 
It shows 3 if I do A->first->next->next->next->next.

I really don't understand and it's starting to get on my nerves, the code is simple and short and I'm still not seeing the mistake.

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code for createNode()? It is important to verify that you are storing the data correctly.

Comment: the whole code is here : http://pastebin.com/C4cunJXF What's strange is that the other keys display as they should.

Comment: Working solution provided in edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so `strcat` adds a terminating zero to the string, you need space for one more char. `strlen` will give you 1, you will allocate a char array with size 2. That's not enough - you need at least 3 for the first char, second char and terminating zero. That's still dangerous, as you don't know the length of the second string. The best solution is thus `char* cat = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1)`.

The current problem is that `char cat[len1+2];` is allocating space on the **stack** (that's where local function variables reside). You're basically keeping a pointer to an address inside of a stack frame, which gets destroyed after the function has finished. The first value works, because this was your last function call and still noone has decided to overwrite this memory (but anyone *is free to do so*). Allocating with `malloc()` will allocate on the **heap** and the value will be available until you explicitly call `free`.

After modifications output is:

```
[43]
{43}
[23]
{23}
[13]
{13}
=13=
=23=
=43=
13 23 43 3 4 2 1
```

A C++ solution can be found at http://pastebin.com/xNzyLQ2N .

Comment: Right (I thought that when I use strcat it was implied).
It doesn't change anything though :(

Comment: Aren't String arrays of Char in C?

Comment: Almost. There's always the additional terminating zero - always 1 additional element you have to keep in mind. Btw I provided an edit above.

Comment: I did what you said (and updated the original post), but the problem stays nearly the same, I can acces to A->first->key but it doesn't appear through showlist though.

Comment: Updated, if you want I can post a pastebin.com of the whole code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm testing it right now and then I'll accept the answer !

Comment: I believe this was the last edit. Enjoy and accept if it helped.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, my code (and most of my suggestions) work for C++. For C, you only have to change `char cat[len1+2];` to `char* cat = malloc(len1+2);`.

Comment: So this wasn't my last edit then :D After thinking a bit more about your problem, I added an explanation why it's behaving exactly how it is.